# Leaflet Marker Cluster: refreshCluster function issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, clustering

I am trying to use the `markers.refreshClusters();` function to refresh the marker icons for a new styled icon I am trying to work with to highlight the selected cluster. Unfortunately, I keep getting the `markers.refreshClusters is not a function` error. Is there a file I am missing for the marker cluster plug-in? I tried updating to latest revision of plug-in but it seems I have the latest.

Comment: Do you have code we can take a look at?

Comment: To give a quick example: `var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, showCoverageOnHover: false, zoomToBoundsOnClick: false ,  iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>' });}` is my markercluster group and `on("clusterclick")` I am trying to run the `markers.refreshClusters();` and then given the error code. I am not doing anything fancy but for some reason it is not recognizing the refreshClusters as a valid function.

Comment: When you `console.log(markers)`, what do you get?

Comment: http://imgur.com/e8MyiA3

Comment: So you'll notice `refreshClusters()` isn't in that list. That means it can't be called on that particular object. If it's a plugin function, it's probably down in either `map` or `options`. So you'd call `markers.options` or `markers.map`. If you want to create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I can try to take a better look at it

Comment: I cannot share my code, is there anyway you could just show a quick example of yourself using it? I am sure from there I can hopefully figure it out and get back to you what I have been doing wrong on my code.

Comment: Sure. I will make one when I get off work. Probably 2-3 hours.

Comment: Sorry it's a little late, but here is a [Leaflet marker cluster example](http://jsfiddle.net/bddavidson/0ab2hm67/)

Comment: [Updated marker cluster link](http://jsfiddle.net/bddavidson/0ab2hm67/1/). Looks like the previous one was linked incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks BDD, but I was talking about implementing the `refreshClusters()` mentioned on the documentation. Either way thank you for taking your own time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote the `refreshClusters()` method a few weeks ago. Unfortunately it did not make it yet to the distributed version on GitHub nor to the one provided by MapBox, even though the documentation already mentions it.

You can easily add it yourself by [copying the code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerClusterGroup.Refresh.js) into your script. Just make sure to include it before calling the method.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0ab2hm67/3/

Definitely this new method is helpful to more and more people. Please feel free to ask for a new version to include it by posting on the library issue page.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought since documentation had it it would be a native function. You are awesome, thank you for your work.